# How is exponentiation with non-integer numbers defined for functions?

Tags: functions

For example, $\sin^{0.5}(x)$ seems nonsensical to me, yet, entering something such as `sin^i` into something such as WolframAlpha results in $\sin^i(x)$, not $\sin(x)^i$. Given that there is a clear difference between $\sin^{-1}(x)$ and $\sin(x)^{-1}$, the former being as far as I know $\sin^{-1} : [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$
and the latter simply $\sin(x)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\sin(x)}$, I'd assume this to be more than a display error. So what does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's one of the reasons why one should never use $\sin^{-1}$ for the inverse function of sine. The other reason is that $\sin $ has no inverse function, not being a bijection. What really has an inverse is the `restriction` of $\sin$  to a convenient interval, namely $\;\bigl[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\bigr]$. Its real name is `\arcsin`. Only the hand-held calculators should know the notation $\sin^{-1}$, due to the size of keys.

This being said, the definition of $x^y$, in the domain of real functions is
$$ x^y =\mathrm e^{y\ln x}.$$